# How do I return the UIColor of an object in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using XCTest and want to test the navBar of a tableView to see if it is set to a specific colour.

How do I reference the colour of the navBar?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the navigation bar, you likely want `navigationBar.barTintColor` for the background color.

Comment: This is what I initially used but it seems to be "NULL" in the test.

Comment: If it is null, it means a default color is used. Are you using a custom color?

Comment: I've set the bar to red in the view controller. This question explains further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738294/how-do-i-use-xctest-to-test-if-a-navigationbar-is-not-set-to-a-specific-colour-i