# How do I use XCTest to test if a navigationBar is not set to a specific colour in objective-C?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xctest

Trying to test for navigationBar colour of a table view controller. I've set the barTintColor of the navigationController in the table view controller.

**I have written the following test:**

```
- (void)testNavBarColourOfMasterViewController
{
    VAGMasterViewController *mvc = [[VAGMasterViewController alloc] init];
    [mvc view];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects([[[mvc navigationController] navigationBar] barTintColor], [UIColor whiteColor]);
}
```

**Error:**

```
test failure: -[VAGMasterViewControllerTests testNavBarColourOfMasterViewController] failed: (([[[mvc navigationController] navigationBar] barTintColor]) equal to ([UIColor whiteColor])) failed: ("(null)") is not equal to ("UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1")
```

Apparently when I try to read the colour of the barTintColor it is null. How can this be if it's set in viewDidLoad in the controller?

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you logged the mvc.navigationController and mvc.navigationContoller.navigationBar to make sure that neither of them is nil?

Comment: Why did you start a new question instead of editing your existing one on the same topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return the UIColor of an object in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738090/how-do-i-return-the-uicolor-of-an-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: Two different questions in my opinion. I feel this one is dedicated to XCTest. Also @rdelmar I logged both and neither are nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating just a view controller will lead to the navigation controller (and thus, the bar) being `nil`. The solution is to create a navigation controller:

```
- (void)testNavBarColourOfMasterViewController
{
    VAGMasterViewController *mvc = [[VAGMasterViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc];
    [mvc view];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects([[[mvc navigationController] navigationBar] barTintColor], [UIColor whiteColor]);
}
```

Also, it is not good practice to access the navigation controller or its properties (in this case, bar) in `viewDidLoad`, because the view loading may be triggered before the navigation controller has linked itself with the view controller, causing issues.

Comment: This worked and to take away unused var warning I created a local var     UINavigationController *nav;.

I'll set those properties in viewWillAppear or didAppear.

Comment: @LondonGuy In that case, remember to call `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` in your tests manually, as they are called when a view enters the hierarchy, which won't happen here.